# Aggreation user visit all url path number in kibana

Tags: logging, kibana, elk

**Target**: Statistics all Api http response cost time and visited count by nginx log.

**Question:**

There some representation url format (log field: path), I don't know how to handle.

- like this:

  > /banner/?display_on=2&type=5&city_id=440100

All URL startwith `/banner/` should belong same api. But kibana statistic url path with query params.

- Another condition like this:

  > /user/

**Is there some advanced settings like regrex pattern to solution it?**